# Group by hours and plot in Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, plot, graph, bokeh

I am trying to get a plot like a stock data in Bokeh like in the link http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/stocks.html

```
2004-01-05,00:00:00,01:00:00,Mon,20504,792
2004-01-05,01:00:00,02:00:00,Mon,16553,783
2004-01-05,02:00:00,03:00:00,Mon,18944,790
2004-01-05,03:00:00,04:00:00,Mon,17534,750
2004-01-06,00:00:00,01:00:00,Tue,17262,747
2004-01-06,01:00:00,02:00:00,Tue,19072,777
2004-01-06,02:00:00,03:00:00,Tue,18275,785
```

I want to use column 2:startTime and 5:count and I want to group by column  `day` and sum the `counts` in respective hours.

code: Does not give the output

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

data = pd.read_csv('one_hour.csv')
data.column = ['date', 'startTime', 'endTime', 'day', 'count', 'unique']

p1 = figure(x_axis_type='startTime', y_axis_type='count', title="counts per hour")
p1.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3
p1.xaxis.axis_label = 'startTime'
p1.yaxis.axis_label = 'count'

output_file("count.html", title="time_graph.py")
show(gridplot([[p1]], plot_width=400, plot_height=400))  # open a browser
```

Reading the column and plot isn't any problem but applying group by and sum operations on the column data is something I am not able to perform.

Appreciate the help, Thanks !

Comment: @JoeR I could get a scatter plot but not the one that I want

Comment: Have you actually created the dataframe? What you posted is not a dataframe.

Comment: @JoeR I have updated with code so far i have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is what you need:

```
data.groupby('startTime')['count'].sum()
```

Output:

```
00:00:00    37766
01:00:00    35625
02:00:00    37219
03:00:00    17534
```

Comment: Thank for the solution but a little confused on how to put it with the bokeh code ?